# How to change directory according to the username?

Tags: python, linux

Is there are a way to change the user directory according to the username, something like

```
os.chdir('/home/arn/cake/')
```

But imagine that I don't know what's the username on that system. How do I find out what's the username, I know that python doesn't have variables so it's hard for me to get the username without variable.

Comment: @MrE: there's no portability requirement in this question, and no notion of a home directory in the other.

Comment: Thank you Mr E , and sorry for the duplication :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pwd.getpwnam(username).pw_dir
```

is the home directory of `username`. The user executing the program has username `os.getlogin()`.

"I know that python doesn't have variables" -- that's nonsense. You obviously mean environment variables, which you can access using `os.getenv` or `os.environ`.

Comment: Thank you larsmans, both of your comments are useful :-)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is a better answer but you can always use command calls:

```
import commands
user_dir = commands.getoutput("cd; pwd")
```

Comment: `commands` has disappeared in Python 3.0 and has been deprecated since 2.6.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Thomas, voted with + on your comment :-)